# Stuck with how to get flatpak installed on 21.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, flatpak

I have Ubuntu 21.04.   It came with SNAP.
Seems that has been left behind and how things work on flatpak.

I have some version of Handbrake installed but it is probably old, so I want to update it.
I looked in the SNAP and it doesn't show as installed, and I would prefer to do it directly in case SNAP doesn't keep up with the latest release.

So I went down the "how to install flatpak" rabbit hole.

Looking here:
https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu

Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

But the errors I see when doing this.

All 3 commands.

But errors start right away.

```
me@me-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
Repository: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu/ hirsute main'
Description:
Latest stable versions of Flatpak.

Support policy
--------------

This PPA is provided as a convenience for Ubuntu users, with no guarantee of support. If you are an Ubuntu developer and would like to volunteer to maintain packages for this PPA, please contact us via <https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-flatpak/issues>.

Packages in this PPA are built for the LTS branches of Ubuntu, currently focal, bionic and xenial. The newest LTS branch is treated as the highest priority for updates.

Branches that have reached EOL for non-subscription-based updates are likely to stop receiving updates, or be removed from this PPA, when backports to those branches become too difficult.

Non-LTS branches such as groovy and hirsute are not currently supported by this PPA. If you are an Ubuntu developer and would like to volunteer to maintain packages for this PPA, please contact us via <https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-flatpak/issues>.

Source code for the packages used here
--------------------------------------

* https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-flatpak
* https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-flatpak-builder
* https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-xdg-desktop-portal
* https://github.com/flatpak/ppa-xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

These packages are built from the ppa/stable/focal, ppa/stable/bionic, ppa/stable/xenial branches.

Development versions of these packages
--------------------------------------

https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/development provides newer prereleases of Flatpak from its development branch.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-hirsute.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-hirsute.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable.gpg with fingerprint 5C6D153A17C02C337EF6C663B8B9D41229DFA5F5
Ign:1 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease   
Ign:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease 
Ign:4 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease  
Err:5 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:6 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:7 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:8 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                
Ign:10 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute InRelease                                      
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Ign:12 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates InRelease
Ign:13 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute Release                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:17 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Err:18 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
me@me-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                   
Ign:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                 
Ign:4 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease                                  
Err:5 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release                                                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:6 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:7 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:8 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease     
Ign:10 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute InRelease
Ign:11 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates InRelease                   
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Ign:13 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Err:16 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:18 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.48 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com hirsute-proposed Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
me@me-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install flatpak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kodi-visualization-spectrum libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libopts25 sntp vlc-bin vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-access-extra
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
Suggested packages:
  malcontent-gui
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flatpak libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,446 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,670 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 libmalcontent-0-0 amd64 0.10.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:2 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 libostree-1-1 amd64 2020.8-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Ign:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe amd64 flatpak amd64 1.10.2-1ubuntu1.1
Err:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe amd64 flatpak amd64 1.10.2-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/malcontent/libmalcontent-0-0_0.10.0-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ostree/libostree-1-1_2020.8-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/flatpak/flatpak_1.10.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
me@me-desktop:~/Downloads$
```

So that isn't going to work.

`--fix-missing` gives similar errors.

Someone - please.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your issue is related to release you're using being EOL (*end of life*).  Your upgrade path is also gone since Ubuntu 21.04 *release-upgraded* to [Ubuntu 21.10 which is now EOL itself](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/).   Use a LTS or *long term support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months; 21.04 should tell you it's the 2021-April (*add 2000 to year number*) release so calculating 9 months from that is easy (2022-Jan for EOL)